# Submitting birth certificate for my kids to get UK visa

Tags: visas, uk

I'm applying for a tourism visa to UK for me and for my family. Do I need to submit my children birth certificates and my marriage certificate with the other documents. I'm applying from UAE and they have a valid UAE ID which is included in the documents.

Comment: First application for you? your family?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, applicants should provide birth certificates, according to the [UK Visas & Immigration supporting documents guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf):

> Under 18s – we **strongly recommend** you submit the following information otherwise it may delay consideration of your application.
>
> - a Birth Certificate or legal document (such as adoption papers) showing the
>     relationship between you and your parent or guardian

However, unless asked, you should not need to include your marriage certificate as, within your application, you'll identify her as your partner with whom you'll travel, as well as other identifying information.